# dynamic width for DataGridColumnTemplate

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'll keep it short, is there any way to define a set of DataGridTemplateColum's and not have their width be static (such as my values 300, 130 and 900 below)? "*", and "Auto" throw exceptions.

I want to have the datagrid be scalable. That is, when the user resizes their browser (it's a Silverlight App), there is not an ugly edge to the data on the right side where the width is greater than the sum of my column sizes.

Looking for something clean, not a code-behind hack if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your datagrid's width property to 100% and don't set a width for at least one column, it should expand to fit the space.